# ReactNative init project with stable version

Tags: react-native

Currently if we init our project using ReactNative, default we using 0.56 version.
This version isn't a stable and every single new project after create I need to install 0.55.4

Is it possible to create instant project with 0.55.4 version of ReactNative ?

Comment: Use the -v flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below mentioned command to create the react native project with the specific react native version.

```
react-native init ProjectName --version react-native@0.55.4
```

Comment: do you have a source where I will find a currently stable version ?

Comment: Here is the list of stable versions:-
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/versions

Comment: @github2017     https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md